# Python: Download Image From Link Without Picture Extension

Tags: python

How would I go about downloading the picture from the following link:

http://cdn.svcs.c2.uclick.com/c2/332b584051f7012f2fd300163e41dd5b

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

urllib2 module of python. You can check the mime type of the url.

```
In [8]: import urllib2

In [9]: img = urllib2.urlopen('http://cdn.svcs.c2.uclick.com/c2/332b584051f7012f2fd300163e41dd5b')

In [10]: img.info().type
Out[10]: 'image/jpeg'
```

Then you can access the content through img.read()

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`urllib`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) or `urllib2` module of python and write the contents of the url in a file named `test.jpg` opened in `write-binary` mode.

```
>>> import urllib
>>> f = open('test.jpg','wb')
>>> f.write(urllib.urlopen('http://cdn.svcs.c2.uclick.com/c2/332b584051f7012f2fd300163e41dd5b').read())
>>> f.close()
```